# How to keep track of function calls inside a react function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a modal manager that allows me to reuse modals with different props, here's roughly what it looks like:

```
const ModalList = ({ list }) => {
  const { makeOpenModal } = useModalManager({ id: 'nameModal', content: props => <div>{props.name}</div> })

  return <ul>
    {list.map(({ id, name }) => <div>
      <button key={id} onClick={makeOpenModal({ name })}>Open modal</button>
    </div>)}
  </ul>
}
```

There is a reducer, context, and a custom hook behind `useModalManager` that keeps track of modals, only ever renders one of them, and allows you to chain modals after each other. But I'm trying to figure out how to build the `makeOpenModal` function such that when you use the function it returns, it syncs the props from that open call with the modal.

In the example above, imagine the name of one of the list items changes while that modal is open, it should then also update the props in the modal.

The big benefit here is that if I have a list of 1000 items, it only ever renders one modal, but it opens it with different props every time you call it from one of the different list items.

This example is over simplified, in reality this hook can be used from different components far apart, only connected by an id (`nameModal` in the example above).